# UPBGE 0.3, where is the "register component" button?

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to follow these instructions:
https://upbge.org/manual/manual/python_components/getting_started/character_controller_templates.html#character-controller-component

I chose the `character_controller_basic.py`

but I cant find the "register component" button anywhere.

The manual shows it is in the Components section, but where is that section?
Not on logic bricks editor.
Not on game object properties (for selected object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in scripting: select this:

[image]

2. in game object properties, game components: press add

[image]

3. enter this:

[image]

if you then press P to play you get:

[image]

Comment: the rotation in the correct Z axis `self.object.applyRotation((0, 0, rotate), True) #original code` did not work, it was spinning the capsule in the X axis! then I had to change to `self.object.applyRotation((rotate, 0, 0), True)` and now I can walk around with the capsule, and spin it properly in the Z (top to down) axis. I wonder if that is a bug in BGE0.3?

Comment: If you provide me your blend file - I can take a look. Could be several reasons…